# Calculating the volume between surfaces by integration

Tags: calculus, integration, 3d, volume

Calculate the volume between these surfaces:

- $x+y+z=1/2$
- $x+y-z=-1/2$
- $z=x^2+y^2$

I'd really appreciate a solution that shows steps and explains the thinking process between them.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know where to start, I've made a 3d render in geogebra, but I'm not sure how to set the boundaries i've seen other examples but those surfaces are usually either other parabolodis or straight lines and not 2d surfaces so... yeah.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Comment: It is not clear to me which side of the each plane you select.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all we observe that the first two surfaces are planes. And they are symmetric around the line $x + y = 0$. We can focus on one of these planes (the one that is highest), and simply ignore the other. My choice is to take $y > -x$.

Secondly we need a strategy to calculate the volume. In this case the obvious choice is to take the difference in $z$ values between two surfaces and to integrate over the variables $x$ and $y$.

In order to perform the integration, we must find the integration bounds. These can be derived from the fact that we integrate until the surfaces intersect, i.e. where the difference in $z$ value equals zero. We have $z = x+y + 1/2 = x^2 + y^2$, which means that the bounds are given by $(x-1/2)^2 + (y-1/2)^2 = 1$. This is the equation for a circle with radius $1$ and center $(1/2, 1/2)$. However, since we work in the half-space $y > -x$, part of this circle is chopped off.

My choice is to divide the truncated circle into two sections: (a) three quarters of the circle described above, and (b) a triangle between the points $(-1/2, 1/2)$, $(1/2, 1/2)$ and $(1/2, -1/2)$.

For the first one we introduce polar coordinates $(r, \phi)$ around the point $(1/2, 1/2)$:

$$I1 = \int_{0}^{1}dr \space r \int_{-\pi /2}^{\pi}d\phi ^\space (x+y+ 1/2 - x^2-y^2)$$

Substituting $x = 1/2 + r\cos(\phi)$ and $y = 1/2 + r\sin(\phi)$ the integral simplifies to

$$I1 = \int_{0}^{1}dr \int_{-\pi /2}^{\pi}d\phi ^\space r(1-r^2) = \frac{3}{8} \pi$$

$$I2 = \int_{-1/2}^{1/2}dx \int_{-x}^{1/2} dy \space (x+y+ 1/2 - x^2-y^2) = 1/3$$

The net volume in region $y > -x$ is equal to $\frac{3}{8} \pi + 1/3$. Due to symmetry the same value is found in the region $y < -x$. Hence the total volume is $\frac{3}{4}\pi + 2/3$.

Comment: I tried using a different method. After I calculated the circle equation(the one with the centre in S(1/2,1/2,3/2)) with the radius of 1 and calculated the bounds of x and y which were 3/2 and -1/2 for x and I wanted to represent y as a product of f(x) so from the circle equation ((x-1/2)^2+(y-1/2)^2=1) I got a domain of -1/2<=x<3/2 and 1/2-sqrt(1-(x-1/2)^2) <= y <= 1/2+sqrt(1-(x-1/2)^2). Then i integrated it and got pi/2/ I used \int \int x+y+1/2 -x^2-y^2 dydx with the above mentioned limits. And for "I2" I also got 1/3, having integrated it using a triple integral, (1/2)

Comment: Here's the wolfram alpha command for my integral, though i feel like i made a mistake somewhere integrate[integrate[integrate[1, {z, x^2 + y^2, x + y + 1/2}], {x, -1/2, 1/2}], {y, -1/2, 1/2}]    <br>
Anyway, my total sum would be π -1/3 and it seems to be contradicting your answer, are you confident in it ? Because I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, thanks for the feedback !